# Is using getters for read-only access pointless in Python?

Tags: python, oop

A method to achieve read-only access is to create a `getter` with no `setter`. This is the implementation in Python.

```py
class Inventory:
    _items: list[Item]

    @property
    def items(self) -> list[Item]:
        return self._items
```

But given that Python has no notion of access restriction, `._items` will still be viewable, readable, and modifiable externally.

[image]

Instead, I could remove the `getter` and treat `.items` as a normal member - since Python won't restrict access either way - reducing code overhead and the number of members to keep track of.

```py
class Inventory:
    items: list[Item]
```

The main benefit I can still see with the `getter` is that it signals to other developers by convention to avoid accessing the member. Are there any other arguments in its support?

Comment: It's not pointless if we can all agree to be adults about it. The `@property` decorator is not superfluous - if you understand that someone who wrote the library knew what logic to wrap into it to avoid a footgun. Your call.

Comment: Your getter example _is_ totally useless. There could be any amount of arbitrary logic in it that would make sense, and the setter could throw errors if you try do something dumb. I do this, for example, in my python binding to a Java server. I do my very best to stop you setting values that I know the server will blow up about - it's easier to signal to you "don't set values out of this range" than let a multi-language stack explode on you

Comment: @roganjosh Why is it useless? Having the `getter` with no `setter` still prevents attempts to set `.items`, which is useful in that it "achieves" read-only access right?

Comment: It's useless in the senses your question raises. If the getter or (absent) setter don't add any logic then it serves no purpose

Comment: You've told me that there's a property you don't think I should touch (the preceeding underscore), but then made a getter that gives it in its original form. There's no utility in that

Comment: Re-reading after this discussion, I think you answered your own question. Yes - plain getters in python is a waste of time. An anti-pattern, even. They only make sense if either the getter or the setter have some extra logic in them

Comment: @roganjosh The utility is to mock read-only access. I provide you a getter for `.items` but I don't provide you a `setter`, preventing you from being able to do `.items = ...`. You are allowed to touch the field, you just cannot modify it. Isn't there utility in this?

Answer (score 1):

> `._items` will still be viewable, readable, and modifiable externally.

Yes, that is correct.
But someone who interacts with it should know better,
since it has clearly been marked Off Limits.
So there is some documentation value in this getter.
For one thing, code linters can notice inappropriate interaction
and ask CI/CD to fail the build.

With that said, the example you show is not a typical
pattern in production python code. A """docstring"""
or other explicit or implicit documentation will
usually make it clear if mutating an object attribute
should not be attempted.

For the truly paranoid, such a getter might choose
to return a shallow copy, or even a deep one, subject
to the obvious tradeoffs.
Notice that the object returned by the example getter
is mutable and can still be trashed by a caller that wants to.

---

Classes inheriting from `Inventory` might choose
to offer such copying behavior.

Independent of whether the parent has a getter,
child classes might also offer "transparent"
behaviors such as logging access frequency or object size.